# Boost libraries for UTF-16 strings?

Tags: c++, boost, utf-16, utf

Are there any boost libraries to help with UTF-16 (or higher) strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing officially in Boost yet, but [Boost.Unicode](http://mathias.gaunard.com/unicode/doc/html/) is actively in development.

Answer (score 6):

I used [ICU](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/icu/) successfully in the past when dealing with encoding in C++.